# ts_vector GROUP BY Month

Tags: sql, postgresql, tsvector

Given the following SQL

```
SELECT 'food' keyword, sum(ndoc) documents, sum(nentry) occurances
FROM ts_stat('SELECT tsvector FROM posts WHERE created_at BETWEEN ''2018-06-01'' AND ''2018-10-01''')
WHERE word IN ('food');
```

I would like to group the result by month, so that the end result contains 3 columns where the 1st column would be the month, the second and third would be the ndoc and nentry.

I tried with the following sql, without luck:

```
SELECT created_at, "food" keyword, sum(ndoc) documents, sum(nentry) occurances
FROM ts_stat('SELECT tsvector, created_at FROM posts WHERE created_at BETWEEN ''2018-06-01'' AND ''2018-10-01''')
WHERE word IN ('makanan')
GROUP BY MONTH(created_at);
```

Can anyone help me ?

**EDIT**

Here's my DDL

```
create table posts
(
    id serial not null
        constraint posts_pkey
            primary key,
    . 
    . . 
    . . .
    . . 
    . 
    created_at timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp,
    location geography(Point,4326),
    tsvector tsvector
)
;

create index index_posts_on_city_id_and_category_id
    on posts (city_id, category_id)
;

create index index_posts_on_city_id_and_district_id
    on posts (city_id, district_id)
;

create index index_posts_on_city_id
    on posts (city_id)
;

create index index_posts_on_category_id
    on posts (category_id)
;

create index index_posts_on_district_id_and_category_id
    on posts (district_id, category_id)
;

create index index_posts_on_subcategory_id
    on posts (subcategory_id)
;

create index index_posts_on_location
    on posts (location)
;

create index index_posts_on_tsvector
    on posts (tsvector)
;
```

Comment: Are you aware that your `BETWEEN` clause will include `2018-10-01` at midnight?

Comment: hi @TimBiegeleisen Yep. I am testing my sql actually and a bit lazy to do greater than / less than

Comment: what is `created_at` column type?

Comment: @dwir182 TIMESTAMP type.

Comment: So where the `created_at` column?

Comment: @dwir182 sorry it got cut off at the wrong line... added now. Please see my edit.

Comment: What's the result in ts_stat? ts_stat use for full text search.. It can't contain date.. Maybe we can use left join use id.. Can you run use id?

Answer (score 0):

Try below using `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at)`

```
 SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) AS mon,
       'food' AS keyword,
        sum(ndoc) documents,
        sum(nentry) occurances
FROM ts_stat('SELECT tsvector, created_at FROM posts WHERE created_at BETWEEN ''2018-06-01'' AND ''2018-10-01''')
WHERE word IN ('makanan')
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at);
```

Comment: hi @fa06, sorry the solution does not work. It says, unknown column "created_at"

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT 
    to_char(created_at, 'MM') as Month, 
    'food' keyword,
    sum(ndoc) documents, 
    sum(nentry) occurances
FROM 
    ts_stat('SELECT tsvector, created_at FROM posts WHERE created_at BETWEEN ''2018-06-01'' AND ''2018-10-01''')
WHERE 
    word IN ('makanan')
GROUP BY 
    to_char(created_at, 'MM');
```

Comment: Tried this, with no luck. created_at is TIMESTAMP type.

Comment: This is the exact error message: [42703] ERROR: column "created_at" does not exist Position: 21